# iOS6 - How to Clear Cache of Homescreen/Standalone Web App?

Tags: ios, html, web-applications

It would appear that Apple have changed the way homescreen/standalone web apps work in iOS 6.  According to various blog posts ([example](http://blog.nsbasic.com/?p=928)) these apps now get their own dedicated space for storing their cached files, sqllite dbs, local storage etc, rather than sharing with the Safari browser like before.

Before iOS 6 when developing I used to go through the following procedure religiously to clear the cache...

1. Remove app from homescreen.
2. Close all pages/tabs in Safari.
3. Finally "Clear Cookies & Data" or "Clear Data" in "Settings" > "Safari".

Unfortunately now that Apple have moved the goal posts this same procedure doesn't seem to work. After clearing, even though my changes are picked up in Safari, when I add to the homescreen and launch the app the old HTML,JS etc is still picked up.

Does anyone know how to reliably fully clear the cache in iOS 6?

Comment: Going through the same frustration now. Would love to hear any updates.

Comment: Looks like quite persistent problem.


Did you try setting:
`<meta content="no" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />`?

If that doesn't fit, try an appcache manifest:
`CACHE MANIFEST  `[newline]
`NETWORK:  `[newline]
`*  `

Comment: Are you developing the app you want to clear the cache for, or are you just a user?

Comment: I am the developer, but I also need to provide instruction to test (i.e. end) users on how to clear their caches also.

Answer (score 9):

I can't verify the cache being cleared properly but this worked for me :

In order to do this, you need to allow Web Inspector on your iOS device.
Go to Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector (it has to be active)
And you have to activate the developer menu on your computer's Safari.
Go to Preferences > Advanced > Activate Developer menu

1. Connect your device to your computer with the USB cable
2. Go to safari > Developpement > Your Device name > Inspect an App (The app has to be running)
3. This will open The inspector on your computer for the web app
4. While the inspector is open Clear the cache (command + alt + E)
5. With the inspector still open refresh the page on your computer (command + R)

Somehow the Webapp cache got cleared and i got the non-cached code.

Answer (score 8):

I found a a work-around.  Just put a link on the web page itself for users who are having trouble seeing new version...

```
<a href="javascript:top.frames.location.reload();">refresh</a>
```

It works just like the iPhone/iPad refresh button on the address bar!

Comment: DOn't get why is this downvoted.. this works flawlessly

Comment: I tried almost EVERYTHING and this finally worked! While other answers may prove productive for developers and it's not entirely clear to me who the OP was trying to find a resolution for when he posed his question (developer or user), I would bet heavily that users are certainly NOT going to be connecting to web inspector to clear their cache... so for the User audience this works perfectly. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: You can also pass `true` to reload to cause a force refresh on some browsers (I couldn't find a definitive list but Safari was listed in some of them).

Answer (score 4):

First plug the phone into the computer then open the web app on the phone and Safari on the computer, then you can open the web inspector in Safari from the menu "Develop>Name of phone>title of app" (if you can't see the develop menu you can turn it on in Safari's preferences).

From there you can see/edit the cookies and local storage just like sites on your computer and pressing command+r while the inspector is focused will reload the app on the phone.

Comment: !This is the answer! I had a page I was developing cached so hard I couldn't get it to pick up the cache manifest.

Answer (score 3):

You can [connect your device and open Safari's web inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) on your computer and run `document.location.reload()` in the console tab to reload the page.

Before reloading you can press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to make sure the cache is cleared.

Instead of above you can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page without cache but sometimes it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try appending a unique GET tag to the ends of any and all *href* attributes, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css?
   <?php echo(mt_rand(10000000, 99999999)); ?>
" />
```

This would generate `href="/css/global.css?########"`, with a different number nearly every time. This forces iOS' Safari to pull the "new" page down, as there is no data in its cache originating from the same URI, and there likely never will be (unless you plan on reloading the app millions of times during development :D )

Comment: Unfortunately, the HTML content of the page would still be cached

Comment: @FranciscoH. While this is true, you can also apply this concept to any page on the site, by nesting the PHP tag within hrefs, frames, headers, etc. Unfortunately, however, I have not found a way to use this method to force a new version of the index page to be pulled down.

Comment: I tried everything and this is the only solution that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the iOS6 device has a jailbreak applied, you can use ssh to delete the content of the folder "/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.webapp".

Next time that you start the web app, all files will be re-downloaded from the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to deal with this currently is to wait, but there is a workaround. If you change the name of the file, it will pull the new code. However, if you change it back to the old name before the cache clears, the old code will be used. The cache refreshes periodically and will update eventually. I just had this happen to me with a CSS file that refused to change. Time will fix it, but if you just need it to update for testing, a name change will work.

Comment: Which file needs the name change?  If I change the cache file name, will that fix everything?

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts for a while. Tried clearing the cache on device - no luck. Renaming the page did help, but once you rename it back, you still get the same stale version.
Found the solution yesterday. You need to connect your device to Mac and open Web Inspector in Safari Develop menu. Once in Web Inspector, simply press "Reload page" button on the Inspector's toolbar and - voila - you see the fresh version on your device's screen.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the request you pass to the webview to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: This is a web app accessed from Safari, not a native app using a web view.